# discord.py image command not working when @ other users

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my bot to get the mentioned user pfp, and overlay it with the defined image

When i type "$avatartest", the bot get my discord PFP, and overlay's the original image with it. It works how it should, but my problem is when i want the bot to use other people pfp's. When i try mentioning other users, like " $avatartest @NotSoBot#9555" it only shows my own avatar. What can i do to make it work with mentions?

My code:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()

intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '$', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def avatartest(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
if user == None:
user = ctx.author

    overlay = Image.open('the.png')

    asset = ctx.author.avatar
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    pfp = Image.open(data)

    pfp = pfp.resize((177,177))

    overlay.paste(pfp, (120,212))

    overlay.save("profile.png")

    await ctx.send(file = discord.File("profile.png"))

bot.run(tokenbot)
```

Comment: Sorry for any spelling mistakes, didn't used translator. Also i don't have much time right now, so i may or may not take some time to see or answer any posts, thank yall so much for the attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're still getting the avatar from the `ctx.author` and not from the `user` that you wanted to.

```py
@bot.command()
async def avatartest(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author

    overlay = Image.open('the.png')
    asset = ctx.author.avatar
    #       ^^^^^^^^^^

    ...
```

You can easily fix this by getting it from the `user` instead.

```py
@bot.command()
async def avatartest(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author

    overlay = Image.open('the.png')
    asset = user.avatar
    #       ^^^^

    ...
```